# LaTeX symbol for "divides precisely"

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I sometimes need to write that a certain prime `p^k` *precisely divides* a number `n`, meaning that `p^k | m` but it is not the case that `p^{k+1} | m`. It is often written as: `p^k || m`, where the symbol in the middle is supposed to look like a pair of vertical lines close to one another.

Is there a good way to write this in LaTeX? I am aware of the following possibilities, none of which is fully satisfactory:

1. `p^k \Vert n` gives a nice pair of vertical lines, but the spacing looks wrong.
2. `p^k \mid\mid n` gives the right spacing between numbers and the symbol, but the lines are very far apart.
3. `p^k \mid \!\!\: \mid n`  and `p^k \ \Vert \ n` look about right, but I hear that manually adding spacing is sometimes risky.

Are there any better possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use `\parallel`, which produces the same symbol as `\Vert`, but correctly spaced for a relation symbol.

Another possibility is

```
\newcommand{\pdiv}{\mid\!\mid}
```

and `$a\pdiv b$` would produce

[image]

If you choose `\parallel`, use a new command anyway, so you can easily change your mind later:

```
%\newcommand{\pdiv}{\parallel} % I'll use the next
\newcommand{\pdiv}{\mid\!\mid}
```

There's nothing wrong in using explicit spaces, so long as you know what you're doing. Surely `\:` is not the right spacing command to use, because it introduces a flexible space. If you feel that `\mid\!\mid` is too tight, try

```
\mid\mspace{-2mu}\mid
```

(requires `amsmath`); the command `\!` backs up by 3mu, while the natural space component of `\:` is 4mu, so `\!\!\:` has a natural width of –2mu. But `\mspace{-2mu}` has no flexibility.

Here is a comparison: first row `\mid\!\mid`; second row `\mid\mspace{-2mu}\mid`, third row `\parallel`

[image]

If I had to choose, I'd select the first one. But with a new command you're not bound to a decision until the last time.

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks strange, you need `\parallel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$p^k\parallel n$

$p^k \mid \!\!\: \mid n$ and $p^k \ \Vert \ n$

\end{document}
```

[image]